# Chrome Mac pinned tabs being lost every time I CMD+Q

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mac

Every time I <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> my Chrome session, when I relaunch Chrome my pinned tabs are gone. This is not the same behaviour in Linux or Windows which is why its confusing me.

Does Mac just have this alternative behaviour or is this a problem with my Mac?

I also notice that the LastPass extension does not remember my email address, whereas in Linux and Windows it does.

- Chrome 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) 64-bit
- Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Have you tried a new profile in Chrome? Or resetting it?

Comment: Check System Prefs>General & make sure you don't have "Close windows when quitting an app" switched on.

Comment: @Tetsujin Perfect! That fixed my issue! can you formulate it into an answer so I can give you the rep? thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on a hunch in comments…

System Prefs > General > Close windows when quitting an app …uncheck.